# Are their built-in Toggle Switches in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, togglebutton

I've been looking for a good way to put a toggle switch into a design. But, when searching for a standard way to do this, all I came across are toggle switches created through a combination of HTML and CSS. See an example from [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) below:

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Rounded switch -->
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Is this the only way of creating toggle switches in HTML5?

Comment: A toggle switch is just a binary input, HTML covers binary inputs with checkboxes (and in a sense, radio buttons) which can be styled to look however you need them to.

Comment: @DBS Okay, interesting. Giving the ubiquity of toggle switches it seems strange to me there isn't a basic version. Is there a reason for that? i.e. the styling would be complicated enough that you may as well make your own one anyway?

Comment: Simply because when HTML was invented, checkboxes were the standard thing for binary inputs. Switches are a recent smartphone-fueled development which serves the exact same purpose. HTML isn’t obliged to chase every UI trend, especially when you can do it yourself with CSS.

Comment: When styling it you don't even need to add additional elements, you can achieve the same effect with animation and all with just a background or two.

Comment: There is a new [switch control](https://webkit.org/blog/15054/an-html-switch-control/) being introduced, but only in webkit for now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A toggle switch is essentially a checkbox, with a certain type of styling.

Both are binary inputs, so having both as different HTML elements would be a bit redundant. Checkboxes were the standard long before switches came along, and adding a whole new element to HTML for a small UI difference wouldn't make much sense.

Hope that helps!